# How to use different class objects in one array?

Tags: java

I have one problem because I wanna put different classes in one array.

I have 5 classes: Dog, Kitchen, Cat, Cow, Bird

How can I put all this classes to one array?

Comment: All these classes present animals so you can create a generic type like Animal and use inheritance

Comment: @esprittn A `Kitchen` is an `Animal`?

Comment: @Logan Maybe those are Kittens living in the kitchen.

Comment: @GhostCat Possibly!

Answer (score 2):

Because every data type in Java extends [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), you can just use an object array:

```
Object[] array = {new Dog(), new Kitchen(), new Cat(), new Cow(), new Bird()};
```

Primitives do not extend object, although [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) allows for primitives to be converted to objects when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use object array as following:-

```
Object[] objects = {new Dog(), new Kitchen(), new Cat(), new Bird()};
```